# Convert Object to Array For a User In MongoDB

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb

I have multiple users in my collection and each user has an object of sessions shown below

```
{
  user: 'adam',
  sessions: {
   key: some-value,
   key: some-value
  }
} 
{
  user: 'chris',
  sessions: {
   key: some-value,
   key: some-value
  }
}
```

I fetch the document on the basis of the user name. let us say i want the sessions of adam.

So I run **db.collection.find({ user: 'Adam' })** which gives me full document of adam. Now I want the sessions of **'Adam'** but the sessions object should be converted into an array of objects like this :

```
{
 user: 'adam'
 sessions : [ { key: value },{ key: value } ]
}
```

I want to convert the sessions of user into an object that means i want to do **$objectToArray** but on a specific username not the full collection.

Just the user I want.

**Explanation:**

I am running node as backend and i have a route called **'getuserdata'** which gets data for a specific user based on the username. So when i will hit that route with username adam and it will get the data from the DB. The sessions of adam should come in an **array of objects** like shown above instead of an object which is in the **db.**

**What i am doing**

I am running a **for-in** loop on the back-end to convert them into array of objects but it is slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `$map` in project part,

- `$map` input sessions as array to convert using `$objectToArray`,
- inside map convert array of object key and value to `$arrayToObject`

```
db.collection.find(
{ user: "adam" },
{
  user: 1,
  sessions: {
    $map: {
      input: { $objectToArray: "$sessions" },
      in: { $arrayToObject: [["$$this"]] }
    }
  }
})
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-gz-S8ppTX6)

Comment: can you provide some example, i am not getting exactly.

Comment: Im asking about `$arrayToObject: [["$$this"]]`

Comment: sessions are converted to array from input using $objectToArray and next inside `in` we will get `k` and `v` object format, so we are just converting that `{k: "', v: ""}` and `$$this` contains this `{k: "', v: ""}` , we are just converting to array using just `[]` brackets, `[$$this]` means this => `[{k: "', v: ""}]` and `$arrayToObject` convert that array to object format means original key and value format.one by one. hop i explained properly..

Answer (score 1):

```
//run from mongodb client
//sample user data preparation
> db.users15.find();
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4fbfbc3372ab5da3a605ac"), "user" : "adam", "sessions" : { "key1" : 1123, "key2" : 1124 } }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4fbfbc3372ab5da3a605ad"), "user" : "chris", "sessions" : { "key1" : 2122, "key2" : 2134 } }
// Mongo query, variable defined an user for dynamic passing in match condition
> var v_user = "adam"
> db.users15.aggregate([
...  {$match:{user:v_user}},
...  {$project:{user:1,
...             sessionArray:{$objectToArray:"$sessions"}
...         }
...     }
... ]);
//output showing conversion from session object to array for key value pair
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5f4fbfbc3372ab5da3a605ac"), "user" : "adam", "sessionArray" : [ { "k" : "key1", "v" : 1123 }, { "k" : "key2", "v" : 1124 } ] }
>
//Further,the mongo query gives correct output for nested objects as well.
//Example below.
> db.users15.find().pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4fbfbc3372ab5da3a605ac"),
        "user" : "adam",
        "sessions" : {
                "key1" : 1123,
                "key2" : 1124
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f4fbfbc3372ab5da3a605ad"),
        "user" : "chris",
        "sessions" : {
                "key1" : 2122,
                "key2" : 2134
        }
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5069ed3372ab5da3a605ae"),
        "user" : "sriny",
        "sessions" : {
                "key1" : 2122,
                "key2" : 2134,
                "key3" : {
                        "server1" : 2344,
                        "server2" : 9999
                }
        }
}
>
> var v_user = "sriny"
> db.users15.aggregate([
...  {$match:{user:v_user}},
...  {$project:{user:1,
...             sessionArray:{$objectToArray:"$sessions"}
...         }
...     }
... ]).pretty();
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5f5069ed3372ab5da3a605ae"),
        "user" : "sriny",
        "sessionArray" : [
                {
                        "k" : "key1",
                        "v" : 2122
                },
                {
                        "k" : "key2",
                        "v" : 2134
                },
                {
                        "k" : "key3",
                        "v" : {
                                "server1" : 2344,
                                "server2" : 9999
                        }
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take for example this object

```
const obj = { 
  key1: "value1",
  key2: "value2"
}
```

We can [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) this to pattern `[ { key1: value1 }, { key2: value2 } ]` using a map on the object keys

```
const arrayFromObj = Object.keys(obj).map(value => { 

    return { value: obj[value] }
  
})
```